# recuperar posiçao de item em listview

Tags: java, android, listview

quando a pessoa clica no item A no fragmento `categoria` eu precisaria levar pra uma activity. E quando clicar no item B levar pra outra activity, pra eu poder fazer os filtros.

Aqui a classe dos itens:

```
public class Itens {

    private int imagem;

    public Itens(int imagem) {
        this.imagem = imagem;
    }

    public int getImagem() {
        return imagem;
    }

    public void setImagem(int imagem) {
        this.imagem = imagem;
    }
}
```

Aqui o adapter:

```
public class CategoriaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Itens> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Itens> lista;

    public CategoriaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Itens> lista) {
        super(context,0,lista);
        this.context = context;
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Itens itemPosicao = this.lista.get(position);
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.lista_categoria,null);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_lista_categoria);
        imageView.setImageResource(itemPosicao.getImagem());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

E aqui o fragmento:

```
public class PorCategoria extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<Itens> adapter;

    public PorCategoria() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_por_categoria, container, false);

        final ArrayList<Itens> lista = new ArrayList<Itens>();

        Itens a = new Itens(R.drawable.categoria1);
        Itens b = new Itens(R.drawable.categoria2);
        Itens c = new Itens(R.drawable.categoria3);
        Itens d = new Itens(R.drawable.categoria4);
        Itens e = new Itens(R.drawable.categoria5);

        lista.add(a);
        lista.add(b);
        lista.add(c);
        lista.add(d);
        lista.add(e);

        adapter = new CategoriaAdapter(getActivity(),lista);
        ListView listaCategoria = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_categoria);
        listaCategoria.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o método `setOnItemClickListener()`. Veja:

```
listaCategoria.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long arg3) {

            // o int position representa a posição no qual você clicou
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Posição: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if(position == 0){
                // aqui você coloca seu intent para qual activity quer ir
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta mas nao consigo dar o getItemAtposition fica vermelho

Comment: @FelipeMoreira corrigi pra você. li sua pergunta novamente, e percebi o que queria. Veja.

Comment: muitíssimo obrigado amigo, conseguir dar continuidade ao meu projeto

Comment: @FelipeMoreira se a resposta te ajudou, você pode valida-la para ajudar outras pessoas.